# Model Validation problem when render same model twice pn same page

Tags: asp.net-mvc, validation, asp.net-mvc-3

I am Using  MVC 3.0

My issue is on one page I am using same model twice with some validation. But client side validation are gets applied for first model only.

My code in view is

```
 @using (Html.BeginDTPanel("Applicant"))
        {
         <text>
            @Html.Partial("~/areas/common/views/shared/_customer.cshtml", Model.Applicant)
         </text>    
        }

        @{ var state = Model.Mode == ActionMode.Edit && Model.CoApplicant.TaxIdentifierLastFour != null ? "expanded" : "collapsed"; }
        @using (Html.BeginDTPanel("Co-applicant", state))
        {
         <text>
            @Html.Partial("~/areas/common/views/shared/_customer.cshtml", Model.CoApplicant)
         </text>    
        }
```

**_Customer.cshtml code is something like**

```
@Html.LabelFor(Model.Prefix, m => m.FirstName, "First Name")
```

@Html.TextBoxFor(Model.Prefix, m => m.FirstName)
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(Model.Prefix, m => m.FirstName)

@Html.LabelFor(Model.Prefix, m => m.MiddleName, "Middle Initial")
@Html.TextBoxFor(Model.Prefix, m => m.MiddleName)
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(Model.Prefix, m => m.MiddleName)

@Html.LabelFor(Model.Prefix, m => m.LastName, "Last Name")
@Html.TextBoxFor(Model.Prefix, m => m.LastName)
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(Model.Prefix, m => m.LastName)

**Validation model which I used is as below**

[RequiredIf(ErrorMessage="Please Enter First Name")]
        [StringLength(15, ErrorMessage = "Maximum character limit exceeded")]
        [RegularExpression(@"^[a-zA-Z0-9 ]+(([\'\,.-][a-zA-Z0-9 ])?[a-zA-Z0-9 ]*)*$", ErrorMessage = "Incorrect First Name")]
        public string FirstName { get; set; }

```
    [StringLength(1, ErrorMessage = "Maximum character limit exceeded")]
    [RegularExpression(@"^[a-zA-Z ]$", ErrorMessage = "Incorrect Middle Initial")]
    public string MiddleName { get; set; }

    [RequiredIf(ErrorMessage = "Please Enter Last Name")]
    [StringLength(25, ErrorMessage = "Maximum character limit exceeded")]
    [RegularExpression(@"^[a-zA-Z0-9 ]+(([\'\,\.\-][a-zA-Z0-9 ])?[a-zA-Z0-9 ]*)*$", ErrorMessage = "Incorrect Last Name")]
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    [RequiredIf(ErrorMessage = "Please Enter SSN")]
    [StringLength(11, ErrorMessage = "Maximum character limit exceeded")]
    [SouciaSecurityNumber(ErrorMessage ="Invalid SSN")]
    [RegularExpression(@"^([0-9]\d{2}|7[0-6]\d|77[0-2])([ \-]?)(\d{2})\2(\d{4})$", ErrorMessage = "InValid SSN")]
    public string TaxIdentifier { get; set; }
```

The exact issues is here I am using same model with validation for both applicant and coapplicant. but when page render validation actully applies to first Applicant only.

When I checked view source 
validation related code rendered for Applicant only.

But I need to apply validation for both the mode.

Please suggest any solution you have.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A did add follwing line to my .cshtml file its working now.

@{ ViewData.TemplateInfo = new System.Web.Mvc.TemplateInfo { HtmlFieldPrefix = Model.Prefix }; }

Answer (score 2):

Use editor templates instead of standard partials. Basically just move `_customer.cshtml` to `/Shared/EditorTemplates/Customer.cshtml` and then use

```
@Html.EditorFor(m => m.Applicant)
@Html.EditorFor(m => m.CoApplicant)
```

Comment: Using this solution, All the properties in the model render with html on the form. I want to use _customer.cshtml as template.